# Calculating entropy in grouped panel data

Tags: r, package, transform, entropy, inequality

I have a grouped data structure (different households answering a weekly opinion poll) and I observe every household over 52 weeks (in the example 4 weeks). Now I want to indicate the value of a household at a given point in time using entropy. The value of a household participating in the poll should be higher, if the household didn't participate in the past weeks. So a household always answering the poll should have a lower value in these 4 given weeks than a household answering every two weeks in the two weeks when it does participate. It's important that for a given household the inequality measure varies over weeks.

What's the best way to do so? If it's entropy, how do I apply it to a panel data structure using R?

The data structure is as follows:

```
da_poll <- data.frame(household = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), participation = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0))

da_poll
   household participation
1          1             1
2          1             1
3          1             1
4          1             1
5          2             0
6          2             0
7          2             0
8          2             1
9          3             0
10         3             1
11         3             0
12         3             1
13         4             1
14         4             1
15         4             1
16         4             0

# 1 indicates participation, 0 no participation.
```

I have tried to group it by households, but then I only get one value for each household:

```
da_poll %>% 
  group_by(household) %>%
  mutate(entropy = entropy(participation))

A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   household [4]
   household  week participation entropy
       <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
 1         1     1             1   1.39 
 2         1     2             1   1.39 
 3         1     3             1   1.39 
 4         1     4             1   1.39 
 5         2     1             0   0    
 6         2     2             0   0    
 7         2     3             0   0    
 8         2     4             1   0    
 9         3     1             0   0.693
10         3     2             1   0.693
11         3     3             0   0.693
12         3     4             1   0.693
13         4     1             1   1.10 
14         4     2             1   1.10 
15         4     3             1   1.10 
16         4     4             0   1.10
```

If I group based in household and week, I also get something strange:

```
da_poll %>% 
  group_by(household, week) %>%
  mutate(entropy = entropy(participation))
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   household, week [16]
   household  week participation entropy
       <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
 1         1     1             1       0
 2         1     2             1       0
 3         1     3             1       0
 4         1     4             1       0
 5         2     1             0      NA
 6         2     2             0      NA
 7         2     3             0      NA
 8         2     4             1       0
 9         3     1             0      NA
10         3     2             1       0
11         3     3             0      NA
12         3     4             1       0
13         4     1             1       0
14         4     2             1       0
15         4     3             1       0
16         4     4             0      NA
```

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: I want to know how it works in R, I have tried the entropy package on my dataset, but it seems to ingore the grouped data structure. I have added the question in my description, sorry.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where things go awry. As it stands you question is not specific enough.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, hope it's better now.

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I need. I want it to vary over weeks for each household. So, for example, in week 2, household 3 should have a very high value because it's participating for the first time while the other household have already answered in week 1 (household 1 and 4) or still do not participate (household 2).

Comment: 1) All weeks get the same entropy value because the entropy is calculated from the all 4 weeks and then added to each record within a household. 2) there is no entropy in a system in with a single value, and `entropy(0)` returns NA because because the you're eventually taking the log of 0 in the entropy calc... i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the entropy cummulatively you need to write your own cummulative function. There is probably a more tidyverse-idomatic way do it but this is what I came up with. Based on your post and your comments, entropy may not be the metric you are looking for.

```
cummulEntropy <- function(x){
   unlist(lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) entropy::entropy(x[1:i]))) 
 }

 da_poll %>% 
    group_by(household) %>% 
    mutate(entropy=cummulEntropy(participation))
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   household [4]
#   household participation entropy
#       <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1         1             1   0    
# 2         1             1   0.693
# 3         1             1   1.10 
# 4         1             1   1.39 
# 5         2             0  NA    
# 6         2             0  NA    
# 7         2             0  NA    
# 8         2             1   0    
# 9         3             0  NA    
#10         3             1   0    
#11         3             0   0    
#12         3             1   0.693
#13         4             1   0    
#14         4             1   0.693
#15         4             1   1.10 
#16         4             0   1.10
```

Comment: Thank you, it's definitely getting closer! Do you maybe have a recommendation for another metric that might quantify what I am looking for?